# While loop running too many times

Tags: swift, while-loop

I'm developing a game simulation in Swift and want a function to run until there is a change in possession.

My while loop is almost working, however it seems to run one too many times. I've read through a few other questions and can't seem to figure it out...(i'm a newbie to this!)

```
var possession = 0

func runPlay() -> String {
// Run play scenario
// If meets criteria for possession change then run following, otherwise leave 'possession' unchanged
    if possession == 0 {
        possession = 1
    }
    else {
        possession = 0
    }
// Return description of the play.
return commentary
}

func runPossession() -> String {
    let possFlag = possession
    repeat {
        runPlay()
    } while possFlag == possession
    return commentary
}
```

This runs through, but stops one loop too late. i.e. it runs the first scenario after possession has changed. Confused.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a Bool type?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to coding swift. I'm aware Bool is true/false, but don't understand how to apply your suggestion here.

Comment: `var possession = false` then if you want to toggle its value you can negate it `possession = !possession`. It will even make it easier for you when adding your conditions `if possession {` or `while possession`

Comment: @LeoDabus `possession.toggle()`

Comment: @LeoDabus Used it in 4.2 (https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0199-bool-toggle.md)

Comment: yes just saw Xcode 10.0+

Comment: I've got closer to understanding why it is happening, but no less confused. In an attempt to step through and understand where i'm going wrong, i replicated the runPlay function and renamed runDrive. I then added the possFlag while loop constraint and still stepping through once too many times.

HOWEVER, when i also add an if possFlag constraint to runPlay too, then suddenly runDrive works as expected. Even though i'm not calling runPlay...

Thanks for your help so far @LeoDabus and ielyamani - any thoughts on this.

Comment: Unclear what the while loop is even for. Please step back from your code and just tell us, in words, what you are trying to achieve. Your structure makes no sense because `runPlay` will not return `commentary` until the _last_ play before possession changes, so you will lose all the other plays commentaries.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like that:

```
while possFlag == possession {
    runPlay()
}
```

You are making a do while, first you perform a pass through and then you check the statement, which leads to one more iteration than what you would want to.
You can find more information about [Control Flow](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) at Swift documentation.

An entire different option would be get rid of the while statement. Maybe do something more "reactive" instead. You for example could check if your possession are equal to `possFlag` inside a `didSet` of possession.

```
var possession: Bool = False {
    didSet { 
        if possFlag == possession { 
            // do what you need
        }
}
```

And you keep going with the rest of your game logic.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. I tried this first and still get the same outcome